# Matlab: Strange Attempted to access error... index must be pos. int or logical

Tags: matlab, indexing, syntax-error

I am not new to Matlab, but I have a very strange error I have not encountered before under the circumstances. I have tried to make a simplified version of my code to demonstrate the error I am getting. Basically, I have the indexing error, but the index being accessed is a positive integer.

I am wondering if it may have something to do with the format of the index number. Anyway, any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
t=(0:0.00001:2*pi);
Cir(1,1:length(t)) = 0;
Cir(2,1:length(t)) = 0;
Cir(3,1:length(t)) = 0;

D0(1:length(t)) = 0;

% Search for the first minimum
[min1D0,t1Found] = min(abs(D0(1:length(t)/2)));
% Search for the second minimum
[min2D0,t2Found] = min(abs(D0(length(t)/2:length(t))));
t2Found = t2Found + length(t)./2; % Add tIndex/2 to correct the index

C1 = [Cir(1,t1Found),Cir(2,t1Found),Cir(3,t1Found)];
C2 = [Cir(1,t2Found),Cir(2,t2Found),Cir(3,t2Found)];
```

The output is:

```
Warning: Integer operands are required for colon operator when used as index 
Warning: Integer operands are required for colon operator when used as index 
??? Attempted to access Cir(1,314161); index must be a positive integer or logical.
```

Note: I am using R2009b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`length(t)` is 628319, which is an odd number.

You are trying to access

```
DO(length(t)/2)
```

where `length(t)/2` is 314159.5.

Array indices need to be integers, that is why you are getting that warning.

The same thing happens with `t2Found`. It is not an integer.

```
t2Found = t2Found + length(t)./2;
```

results in 314160.5.

---

As a side note, you can use the `zeros` function for preallocation.

```
Cir = zeros(3, length(t));
```

will give you the same result.

Comment: You are correct. I suppose it is a little late and I was not thinking properly :)... However, The warning was for the most part fine. The problem was the index error which arose for a different reason. I will post my findings below.

Comment: HebeleHododo is correct. The index was a problem, however, the subscript error was a number formatting problem.

It may be a problem with the version (R2009b). 

Solution: t2Found does not register as an integer.

    >> isinteger(t2Found)    
    ans =    
         0

To fix this, you can do this:

    t2Found = int32(t2Found);

Comment: @MasonN t2Found is not an integer. Rounding may cause you more trouble in the long run.